# Delete foreign key with primary key reference

Tags: sql-server

I tried many forums but was not satisfied - I have a table that has a primary key and foreign key relation.

I have to delete table rows with primary key so I need to remove the constraints before deleting.

I used:

```
delete from [docd_metadata].[docd_metadata].[STATEMENT_IMAGES] 
where [statement_image_id]= 05291520275
```

I got error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "fk_stmnt_image_StmntImageId". The conflict occurred in database "docd_metadata", table "docd_metadata.STATEMENT_CAMPAIGN", column 'STATEMENT_IMAGE_ID'.

so I tried :

```
ALTER TABLE[docd_metadata].[docd_metadata].[STATEMENT_IMAGES] 
DROP CONSTRAINT [fk_stmnt_image_StmntImageId]
```

Now I am getting :

> Constraint 'fk_stmnt_image_StmntImageId' does not belong to table 'STATEMENT_IMAGES'

Schema:

[image: Schema of table constraints is]

Also:

[image]

Any suggestion please?

Comment: delete the child records first, then the parent records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really closely read the error message, it's clear that the FK constraint is on table `docd_metadata.STATEMENT_CAMPAIGN` and not on `STATEMENT_IMAGES` - so therefore, you must use this SQL to drop the FK constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [docd_metadata].[STATEMENT_CAMPAIGN] 
DROP CONSTRAINT [fk_stmnt_image_StmntImageId]
```

The FK goes from table `[docd_metadata].[STATEMENT_CAMPAIGN]` (column `STATEMENT_IMAGE_ID`) to `[docd_metadata].[STATEMENT_IMAGES]` - one table has the primary key, which another table references via its foreign key.

Comment: oh...My bad.Thanks a lot.I dont know sometime make such stupid mistake.Thanks again